Order of matching-info fields within lwc record picker
I want to define order of fields for which typed values will be mathced.
Record picker has the attribute matching-info when we can define:
    matchingInfo: {
        primaryField: { fieldPath: 'Name' },
        additionalFields: [ { fieldPath: 'CustomField__c' } ]
    },

Why results are mixed and not showed according order of matching?
Is it possible to accompish that functionality with standard record picker?
